# Does integral of product of weak, strong and weak-* convergent sequences converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain and suppose that
$$f_n \to f \text{ in $L^2(\Omega)$}$$
$$g_n \rightharpoonup g \text{ in $L^2(\Omega)$}$$
$$h_n \rightharpoonup^* h \text{ in $L^\infty(\Omega)$}$$

Can we obtain
$$\int_\Omega f_ng_nh_n \to \int_\Omega fgh?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $f_n\equiv 1$, $g_n(x) = h_n(x) = \sin(n\pi x)$ on $\Omega=(0,1)$. Then $g=h=0$. But $\int_0^1 f_n g_n h_n \to \frac12$.